# An error occurred while installing ruby_postal (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, bundler

Trying to do a bundle install on rails and I keep getting the error:

An error occurred while installing ruby_postal (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

```
Make sure that `gem install ruby_postal -v '1.0.0' --source'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Not sure why the bundle install keeps failing :(

I tried installing Ruby Postal on Mac OSX using:

1. brew install curl autoconf automake libtool pkg-config (installs lib postal C library)
2. git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal (installs lib Postal)
3. cd libpostal
4. ./bootstrap.sh
5. ./configure --datadir=[...some dir with a few GB of space...]
6. make
7. sudo make install

from this guide: https://github.com/openvenues/ruby_postal

Also tried restarting my computer and terminal (I use ITerm2)

Comment: What was the step that you performed before running `bundle install` ?

Comment: Have you tried `gem install ruby_postal` to see what error it returns? if any.

Comment: when I try gem install ruby_postal I get this error: expand.c:1:10: fatal error: 'libpostal/libpostal.h' file not found
#include <libpostal/libpostal.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I found this link and tried reinstalling libpostal and still get the same issue https://github.com/openvenues/node-postal/issues/6

Comment: I'm using MacOS and I went through steps described at the https://github.com/openvenues/ruby_postal#prerequisites without any problems.
I would ensure the `libpostal` installation went correctly by executing `libpostal_data` command or by `which libpostal_data`.